# Design time data - MVVMLight

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am running a wpf application with MVVMLight and trying to get the design time data enabled.

```
public EngineerViewModel(IEngineer engineerService, IProject projectSevice, IBirdsEye birdsEyeService, ISampleData sampleData)
    {
        if (IsInDesignMode)
        {             
            var graph = new ObservableCollection<GraphSample>()
        {
            new GraphSample()
            {
                StandardHours = 75,
                WeekNo = 1
            },

            new GraphSample()
            {
                StandardHours = 70,
                WeekNo = 2
            },                
        };
            SampleGraph = graph;
        }
        else
        {
            _engineerService = engineerService;
            _projectService = projectSevice;
            _birdsEyeService = birdsEyeService;
            _sampleService = sampleData;
            ComShowProject = new RelayCommand(() => ShowProjectDetails());

            LoadProjectsForEngineer();
            SampleGraph = _sampleService.GetSampleGraph();
        }            
    }

private ObservableCollection<GraphSample> _sampleGraph;
    public ObservableCollection<GraphSample> SampleGraph
    {
        get { return _sampleGraph; }
        set { _sampleGraph = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SampleGraph"); }
    }

<dxc:BarSideBySideSeries2D  DataSource="{Binding SampleGraph,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" d:DataContext="{Binding SampleGraph,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                                                                                                ArgumentDataMember="WeekNo" ValueDataMember="StandardHours" Brush="#FFC54F4F" ShowInLegend="True" LabelsVisibility="True" />
```

The data shows up on runtime but not at design.
Any obvious I am missing.
Many thanks
Scott

Answer (score 1):

OK. Solved it using 
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:EngineerViewModel,     IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
and setting up a new constructor which is parameterless.
Scott